# Salvar Bitmap com Alpha

Tags: android, bitmap

Tenho a seguinte classe:

```
public class TesteMultiImage extends ActionBarActivity {

Uri URI;
String ImagePath;
Button button;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_teste_multi_image);

        button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);

        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyy_HHmm");
        final String currentDateandTime = sdf.format(new Date());
        final RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.rl);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                rl.buildDrawingCache();
                Bitmap bmap = rl.getDrawingCache();
                ImagePath = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(
                        getContentResolver(),
                        bmap,
                        "banner" + currentDateandTime,
                        "banner"
                );

                URI = Uri.parse(ImagePath);

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Imagem Salva", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Ela Salva o meu relative layout como um bitmap.
Mas ela salva com um fundo preto, e preciso que salve com um fundo transparente.
Ao tentar configurar :

`bmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Config.ARGB_8888);`

Não funciona. Como resolver?

Answer (score 0):

O modo :

> ARGB_8888

Suporta transparencia, mas inicialmente o canal alfa está 'setado' para opaco.
Você precisa limpar esse padrão.
Teste o seguinte :

```
Canvas c = new Canvas(bm);
c.drawColor(0, Mode.CLEAR);
```

[Fonte (StackOverflow)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11609257/how-to-change-black-background-color-of-bitmap-to-transparent)

Comment: Não entendi o que vc quis dizer.